# get and set the values at the same time django

Tags: django, django-views

How can i do both these things at the same time(same instance)?

```
entity = payment_detail( payment_status='Paid', payment_date=datetime.datetime.now())
a=payment_detail.objects.get(job_post_id=num)
```

Comment: i want to set the payment_status and payment_date and at the same time fetch it on the basis of job_post_id

Comment: so... `payment_detail.detail.filter(job_post_id=num).update(payment_status='Paid', payment_date=datetime.datetime.now())` ?

Comment: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: and if i do this 'a=payment_detail.objects.get(job_post_id=num).update(payment_status='Paid', payment_date=datetime.datetime.now())' it says ''payment_detail' object has no attribute 'update''

Comment: it doesn't work with `get`, because it returns model instance, `filter` returns `QuerySet`. There's too less information to trace that error with 'no meta attribute' - what is your variable `payment_detail`, for example? Put here the whole traceback

Comment: payment_detail is my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
a=payment_detail.objects.get(job_post_id=num)
a.payment_status = 'Paid'
a.payment_date = datetime.datetime.now()
a.save()
```